# How can I smooth noisy time series data to explore possible relationships

Tags: time-series, smoothing

First CV post but prior S.O. user. Thanks for your patience as 'stats' is not my natural habitat.

I have data in the following form, in which I am trying to see if there is a relationship.

- Daily log returns for a series of companies.
- Daily data that may influence the performance of those companies on a lagged basis (for example, independent observer data on how many people enter a set of stores on a given day).

I expect that there is lot of noise in the data, such that the independent observer data on store visits on T-1 will not influence the returns on T, but that aggregated independent data from T-1 to T-30 might, for example, influence the returns from T to T+15.

I'm looking for feedback on how to aggregate these data in a meaningful way to see if there's a relationship, either in return space, or in volatility space. I could certainly draw arbitrary lines (like looking at mean or median visitors for a month and considering monthly returns), but that throws away a lot of data and doesn't seem "right". My intuition is also that I don't have enough data to consider any sort of high-dimensional regression or other analysis that incorporates, for example, 15 lagged observations.

So, what is a reasonable way to aggregate my noisy time series data? Or am I thinking about this wrong?